# Flutter: AppLifecycleState how to use dispose()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and ran into a problem with life cycle. In Page1 I create an instances of AppLifecycleState to just return the current state of the app, which works fine. The problem is when I get to Page2 and click the logout button, it should dispose the AppLifecycleState which means nothing from MyLibrary should be return, but it still returns a value.

I want the AppLifecycleState to be disposed when user clicks on the logout button, what am i missing?

Page1.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/navDraw.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/screens/Login_screen.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/main_title_card.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'my_library.dart';

class setting_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const setting_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<setting_screen> createState() => _setting_screenState();
}

class _setting_screenState extends State<setting_screen> {
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  MyLibrary().MyLibraryX();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed:() {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2(),
            ),
          );
          print("clicked");
        },
        child: Text('Page2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Page2

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/navDraw.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/screens/Login_screen.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/main_title_card.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'my_library.dart';

class setting_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const setting_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<setting_screen> createState() => _setting_screenState();
}

class _setting_screenState extends State<setting_screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed:() {
          MyLibrary().dispose();
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => // Log out page(),
            ),
          );
          print("clicked");
        },
        child: Text('Log out'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my_library.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:poop_alert/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';

class MyLibrary with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState? _state;

  AppLifecycleState? get state => _state;

  MyLibraryX() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    print('WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    print('dispose');
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    _state = state;
    print(_state);
    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;

    if (AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {
      print("Status :" + state.toString());
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.detached) return;

    int counter = 0;

    if (isBackground) {
      print('App closed!');
    } else {
      print('App opened!');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle is not disposing of because whenever you try to call **MyLibrary().dispose()** it will create a new Life cycle because it's initializing the MyLibrary class every time.

So you need to declare or initialise **MyLibrary** class only one time. You can init **MyLibrary()** class as the global level. and try to access it to another file where you want to dispose it.

Page 1.

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:poop_alert/model/user_model.dart';
    import 'package:poop_alert/navDraw.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:poop_alert/screens/home_screen.dart';
    import 'package:poop_alert/screens/Login_screen.dart';
    import 'package:poop_alert/main_title_card.dart';
    import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
    import 'home_screen.dart';
    import 'my_library.dart';

    MyLibrary myLibrary = MyLibrary()

    class setting_screen extends StatefulWidget {
      const setting_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<setting_screen> createState() => _setting_screenState();
    }
    
    class _setting_screenState extends State<setting_screen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        myLibrary.MyLibraryX();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed:() {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Page2(),
                ),
              );
              print("clicked");
            },
            child: Text('Page2'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

page2

```
        class _setting_screenState extends State<setting_screen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed:() {
             myLibrary.dispose();
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => // Log out page(),
                ),
              );
              print("clicked");
            },
            child: Text('Log out'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

change with to extends

```
    class MyLibrary extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState? _state;

  AppLifecycleState? get state => _state;

  MyLibraryX() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    print('WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    print('dispose');
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    _state = state;
    print(_state);
    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;

    if (AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {
      print("Status :" + state.toString());
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.detached) return;

    int counter = 0;

    if (isBackground) {
      print('App closed!');
    } else {
      print('App opened!');
    }
  }
}
```

Try this it will surely solve your problem.